# Run AJAX request using ID from button clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax

In order to use the same AJAX request for several different files, I have an AJAX request which uses the ID of the button that is pressed to select the next file required.

So the button looks like this:

```
<button type="button" id="question_1" onclick="nextQuestion(this.id)">Start the challenge</button>
```

And the start of the AJAX request has the button ID as a parameter:

```
function nextQuestion(buttonID)
```

So the buttonID variable is collected from the button when it is pressed:

```
var splitID = buttonID.split('_'); //split the ID from the end of the button
var questionID = splitID.pop();
```

And then the filename requested is generated using this ID.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","question" + questionID + ".php",true); // concatenate button ID to filename
```

For some reason this doesn't work even though I have it working in another area. I can't work out what I have done wrong. The full AJAX request is:

```
function nextQuestion(buttonID){
quizScore = 0;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("gameWrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
var splitID = buttonID.split('_'); //split the ID from the end of the button
var questionID = splitID.pop();
xmlhttp.open("GET","question" + questionID + ".php",true); // concatenate button ID to filename
}
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'd rather not stray away from what I have here if possible. The exact same functionality is used elsewhere and works fine so I'd rather debug this.

Comment: Instead of `this.id` passing in the param, can you pass `1` or the ID itself?

Comment: I see an open but I don't see a send of xmlhttp.

Comment: @ChiRow yes, that was the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed `xmlhttp.send(null);` function.

Try:

```
function nextQuestion(buttonID){
    quizScore = 0;

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var splitID = buttonID.split('_'); //split the ID from the end of the button
    var questionID = splitID.pop();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","question" + questionID + ".php",true); // concatenate button ID to filename

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("gameWrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.send(null);//send request
}
```